# Give the submit button a Php variable

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

I cannot find the solution to my issue on this forum. I'm trying to give the submit button a PHP value (**unique ID**) by extracting data from my database. I would also like to store the value in a SESSION. The submit button doesn't work when I I give it something other than a String as value.
**Student View:**

```
<pre>

    <?php foreach ($tabinternships as $internship) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="html"><?php echo $internship->id_internship() ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $internship->email_teacher1_internship() ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $internship->email_teacher2_internship() ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $internship->email_responsible_internship() ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $internship->id_promoter_internship() ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $internship->name_enterprise_internship() ?></span></td>     
            <td><?php echo $internship->stage_internship() ?></span></td>       
            <td><input type="radio" name="apply" value="<?php $tabinternship->id_internship() ?>"></td> <!-- Method calls an Object rather than an Array because I'm only displaying the attributes of 1 Object therefore the Array is not required here-->
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</pre>
```

**StudentController:**

```
<pre>

$tabinternships = Db::getInstance()->select_internships();

if(isset($_POST['apply']) && isset($_POST['application'])){
    $_SESSION['apply']= $_POST['apply'];
    $_SESSION['application']= $_POST['application'];
    $_SESSION['redirect']='redirect';
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['application']) && !empty($_SESSION['apply']) && !empty($_SESSION['redirect'])){
    $_SESSION['redirect']='';
    header("Location: index.php?action=formdeux");
    die();
}
</pre>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where is your form code and explain more about your problem with example

Comment: My bad that was supposed to be student form. I would like to identify the row by giving the radio button the row ID. This is to be used later for a query and I would like to stock the ID of the chosen row inside a SESSION. @SamirKarmacharya

Comment: If a student chooses an internship, I would like to store the ID of the internship inside a SESSION. I thought I could stock it inside the value of the radio button. Was I thinking correctly ?

Comment: $tabinternship->id_internship()  value from table right? what happened when 1st user of open the form with id suppose '10' same time user to open the form and submit then user 1st submit. then it will be conflict.  it would be better to extract student info and add unique id and insert into the data base.

Comment: There won't be more than one user at a time so there will not be any conflict. i would just like to stock the unique_id in a SESSION for later use. I don't know why "value" cannot hold the variable. If there is an easier way to retain the ID in a SESSION that would help me a lot. thanks for your anwser @SamirKarmacharya

Comment: Can anyone help ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error, I wasn't using echo when giving a value to the radio input

```
 echo $tabinternship->id_internship()
```